# What's the difference between passing in a value or passing in an address into an interface in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, pointers, interface

Let's say we have a simple interface and implementation:

```golang
type Vertex struct {
    X int
    Y int
}

type Abser interface {
    Abs() float64
}

func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    sum := float64(v.X + v.Y)
    return math.Sqrt(sum)
}
```

Now I have an interface variable:

```golang
var abser Abser
```

I want to set a vertex to it. I am able to set the value of one, or the address of one:

```golang
v := Vertex{1, 1}
abser = v
abser = &v
```

What is the difference between the two? Why does setting the *address* of a Vertex work? How does this tie in with how interfaces work under the hood? I'm still quite new to Go so any help would be much appreciated

Comment: you can assign to an interface a value of any type that implements it. The method set of  `*Vertex` includes methods declared on the non-pointer type `Vertex` as stated in the [specs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Go type system, a method defined using a value-receiver for type `T` is defined for both `T` and `*T`, that is:

```
func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {...}
```

This works for both `v` and `*v`. The method itself always receives a copy of `v`.

A method defined for `*T` is only defined for `*T` and not for `T`. That is:

```
func (v *Vertex) SetX(newx float64) {v.X=newx}
```

The method `SetX` will only work when the receiver is addressable. This is necessary so that you don't write code that loses data. For instance:

```
m:=map[string]Vertex{}
m["a"]=Vertex{}
m["a"].SetX(1) // This fails! m["a"] is not addressable
```

If the above case did not fail, then `SetX` would set a copy of `m["a"]`, and the effects would be lost, because the updated copy is not put back into the map.

Going back to interfaces: your `Abser` interface is implemented by any type that implements `Abs() float64`. Based on the above discussion, both `Vertex` and `*Vertex` implement `Abser`.

Let's say you defined `Vertex.Abs` as:

```
func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {...}
```

Then, only `*Vertex` implements `Abser`, so :

```
abser = v // This would fail
abser = &v // This would work
```

Answer (score 2):

First, in Go, everything is pass by value.

Pointers are passed by value - a copy of the pointer is used.

Slices are passed by value - the pointer to the underlying array, the integer value of the length and the integer value of the capacity are copied.

Interfaces are also passed by value - a copy of the interface value is used.

It helps if you think about it this way.

Now, let's focus on interfaces:

An interface value [consists of two parts](https://cmc.gitbook.io/go-internals/chapter-ii-interfaces#anatomy-of-an-interface):

1. A pointer to an interface table
2. A pointer to the actual value

So when you pass an interface, you're essentially copying two pointers.

Now, for a type to satisfy an interface, it needs to have the methods the interface requires. If any of the methods use a pointer receiver (like `func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {...}` in your example), then you will need a pointer to the value to satisfy the interface and that is why you need to take the address of it.

Let's say none of the methods required a pointer receiver (say `func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {...}`). Then you wouldn't need to specify the address because you would just pass it without taking its address.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: "in Go, everything is pass by value". Slice is a reference type so I don't think this conclusion is correct. Read more [here](https://go.dev/blog/slices-intro)

Comment: Otherwise, this answer is good.

Comment: Actually, slices are passed by value too. Like interfaces, slices are made up of parts - a pointer to the data, the length and capacity. When you pass a slice, these 3 parts are copied - one pointer to the underlying array and 2 integers, just like the page you've linked to says.